# Save data from HANDLE to a file and load data from file to a HANDLE without data loss

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard

Are there any ways (or functions) to save data from `HANDLE` to a file without data loss and load data from file to a `HANDLE`? Assuming that it's a `HANDLE` to a data obtained from `GetClipboardData`.

It would be great if there are answers for all possible data types in clipboard formats but I would look by piority for `CF_LOCALE`, `CF_TEXT`, `CF_OEMTEXT` and `CF_UNICODETEXT`.

I tried to convert from `HANDLE` to pointer but I don't know how to get the data properly (as the handle only point to the first data without further information)

I tried to obtain some useful handle information to know what is possibly inside, but I cannot retrieve it.

There are too few attempts to try as very few (or no one) asked about this question...

Comment: Generally, you use the `GlobalLock()` function to get a usable `void*` pointer from a `HANDLE`. When doing so, you should then copy/save/whatever the pointed-to data immediately and then quickly call `GlobalUnlock()` to release your lock on the clipboard data.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats

Comment: It isn't even possible to save contents, clear and overwrite, then restore the old contents.  You're trying to do that and add file serialization on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-existing solution to handle this task for you.  You will have to do everything manually.

Use [`EnumClipboardFormats()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats) to find which formats are currently available on the clipboard, and [`GetClipboardData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) to access the data of each format.

Or, use [`OleGetClipboard()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-olegetclipboard) to get an [`IDataObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-idataobject) wapping the clipboard's content, and then enumerate and access its data formats using its [`EnumFormatEtc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-enumformatetc) and [`GetData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-getdata) methods.

Then, you can manually write each format's data to your own file as needed, and then later read the data back from your file and put it back on the clipboard according to each format type using [`SetClipboardData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata) or [`OleSetClipboard()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-olesetclipboard).

The data formats of the standard clipboard formats are documented on MSDN:

[Standard Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats)

[Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard)

For example, a `HANDLE` for a `CF_LOCALE` is an `HGLOBAL` handle to an allocated block of memory holding a `LCID` identifier, whereas a `HANDLE` for a `CF_TEXT`/`CF_UNICODETEXT` is an `HGLOBAL` handle to an allocated block of memory holding the actual ANSI/Unicode text characters.

If you want to save/load data for non-standard clipboard formats, you won't be able to do that unless you have intimate knowledge of how their data is formatted in memory for the clipboard to hold.